# External link to php page for global function?

Tags: php, function

I want to create a file which contains global functions and variables that all the other pages (Html and PHP) could call for. I'm struggling in coding on `index.php` at the moment, when it comes to the copyright, I've got the php function which could show the system's year, that I don't want to put this code on the top of the page as I want to put them on a separate file/sheet and have index.php to call for it.

Also I don't want to write the same copyright line on every single page I will create. Where and how could I put this content on and have it called from another files?

Answer (score 2):

not real clear on your q. but .. is http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php and its ilk what you want

Comment: +1 for usage of the word "ilk"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but you can include other PHP files by using either [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), they do the same thing but `require()` causes the page to die if it fails.

syntax:

```
<?php

include("path/to/file.php);

?>
```